# How to keep branch up to date without merge/rebase?

Tags: git

I'm new to git so I don't fully understand the system. I've read a whole bunch of articles and explanations here on stackoverflow, and while I believe they answer my question, I don't understand those answers.

What I would like is to use git to have a feature branch that never gets merged into master, but is always kept up to date with master, except for the main differences in it (a few files that were changed in the initial commit to the branch).

Essentially, what I believe the solution is to merge master into the feature branch, and then reset the head to the previous master, but I assume that will invalidate the merge?

I'm sorry if this is a noob question, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this whole thing.

Comment: *"I've read a whole bunch of articles and explanations here on stackoverflow"* -- have you read the [Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2)?

Comment: What you're describing, namely keeping a branch which never gets merged into `master`, sounds like a bad idea long term.  Eventually, the two branches could diverge to the point where doing a merge with `master` becomes untenable.  Why do you think you need such a branch?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen my use case is supporting a DPI that I can't otherwise support (display size `small` on an `xlarge`, `xxxhdpi` device, leading to a higher DPI that I can set in layouts, please see my previous stackexchange question). So, since I can't let Android set the layout for me, I've decided to create a special layout and keep it in a special branch, but I'd like to merge into that all the base bug fixes, without affecting the app that just works for 99% of devices just to support my own.

Comment: So are you saying that you have special XML layout files, but the rest of the app is identical?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, that's exactly the case.

Comment: @eydryan All code merged in the master branch is easier to maintain. Couldn't you merge your code and enable the feature through a setting or a compilation parameter? So, no need to maintain a branch? Otherwise, that's the `rebase` strategy that fits more your needs

Comment: @Philippe if you have any suggestions as to how to do that, please see my other question on stackexchange. But currently I see no way to do that. It's very strange that git does not allow these parallel but maintained branches, and I just have to manually update things.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem with rebase workflow

if I understand your situation is:

```
* [HEAD master origin/master] a commmit
|
* ... some history
```

you applied a change in a xml file (in another branch here named `modified`)

```
* [HEAD modified] added or modified XML file
|
* [master origin/master] a commmit
|
* ... some history
```

when someone update the remote master branch, you have (if you give a git fetch origin command)

```
* [origin/master] last commmit
|
| * [HEAD modified] added or modified XML file
|/
* [master] a commmit
|
* ... some history
```

## SOLUTION TO UPDATING YOUR MODIFIED BRANCH

1) update your local master version

```
git checkout master
git pull origin
```

and you obtain

```
* [HEAD master origin/master] last commmit
|
| * [modified] added or modified XML file
|/
* a commmit
|
* ... some history
```

2) then

```
git rebase master modified
```

and you obtain

```
* [HEAD modified] added or modified XML file
|
* [master origin/master] last commmit
|
* a commmit
|
* ... some history
```

no reset needed

Comment: Read better my solution... Master and origin master never include your change

But modified version that is just a local branch not existing on the remote, will be up to date with master

Comment: I don't think you understand, I don't want to ever commit that branch to master, or merge/rebase that branch into master, but I always want to keep it updated with any changes in master.

Essentially my use case looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/Mj1lQOh.png

Comment: I also don't just want to have this modified branch only locally, I want it to exist on github as well.